# Should or can an iphone app have a like button

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, fbconnect

I have just implemented FB login and status updates in my app following the sample app in the IOS SDK.

I know it is common practice to have a like button for a page but is it also true for an app?

I mean is it possible to have a like button in my app that when tapped makes an entry on my FB page stating I like the app?

I can't seem to track the like feature down in the docs :-(

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

basically you can add `UIWebView` and put your html tags inside it

check [this](http://petersteinberger.com/2010/06/add-facebook-like-button-with-facebook-connect-iphone-sdk/) and [this](http://angelolloqui.blogspot.com/2010/11/facebook-like-button-on-ios.html) sample they may help you